# Are bhanga and sotapatti synonyms?

Tags: vipassana

Is it correct to say that the vipassana experience of *bhanga* is a synonym  of stream entrance (sotapatti)?

Comment: See also [What is bhanga?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/18418/254)

Comment: With 'bhanga' I mean 'bhanga nana', the 5th insight knowledge, also called  'bhanga-nupassana-nana'. Is it correct to relate this 'experience' with what The Buddha says in verse # 374 of the Dhammapada: 'Fully knowing the arising and passing of the khandhas, One attains joy and delight. For those who know, this is the deathless'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not! Bhanga nana is just the 5th of the [16 stages of insight](http://www.vipassanadhura.com/sixteen.html). Sotapatti starts from the 14th, i.e. Magga nana.